# Getting the album artwork, song name, album name and artist name from an audio file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, id3, appkit

How can I get album artwork, song name, album name and artist name from an audio file? I need to display this without the use of iTunes. Thanks.

Comment: @RJFalconer, any, from MP3 to AAC to WAV to FLAC.

Answer (score 2):

If the file has been indexed by Spotlight, you can use the Metadata framework to examine it. [Create an MDItem for the file](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/MDItemRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MDItemCreateWithURL), then [ask it for the attributes you're interested in](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/MDItemRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MDItemCopyAttributes).

The attributes of a song are:

- `kMDItemTitle`
- `kMDItemAuthors` (Artist(s)—value is an array of strings)
- `kMDItemAlbum`

For the album art, you'll need to [request a thumbnail image for the file from Quick Look](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/QLThumbnailRequest_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/QLThumbnailImageCreate). This isn't foolproof, but should work on most systems, as long as the Quick Look generator for audio files uses the album art if present.

Answer (score 0):

The QuickTime APIs support that, but they aren't ObjC. It'll still work fine though.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2001/qa1135.html

Comment: Care to fix the link? :)

Answer (score 0):

Part of my [SFBAudioEngine](http://github.com/sbooth/SFBAudioEngine) framework supports reading and writing metadata for AIFF, WAVE, AAC, Apple Lossless, MP3, FLAC, Vorbis, Musepack and WavPack. The code is C++ and BSD licensed.

AFAIK there is no native support for reading/writing FLAC metadata (or FLAC audio for that matter) in OS X.

Comment: No MP3? Oh, and I am writing a Cocoa application. I can't use C++ with Carbon since my application in 64 bits.

Comment: Sorry, left that one out by mistake- MP3 is supported!  I edited appropriately.